# EXCLUDE constraint with conditional statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a place table in postgres that contains the following columns

```
 id  | idplace |        date_slot        | type
-----+---------+-------------------------+------------
 1   |     360 | [2023-02-20,2023-02-27) | 'zero'
```

The column type accepts only 3 values ('zero','one' or 'two')
I have created a constraint earlier to exclude any entry that is similar to another and it works. Here is the gist constraint

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY place ADD CONSTRAINT place_idplace_date_slot_excl1 EXCLUDE USING gist (idplace WITH =, type WITH =,date_slot WITH &&)
```

Now I want to modify it with the following rules:

-if the column type is equal to 'zero' do not accept any similar entry.

-if the column type is equal to 'one' accept only one another entry that contains 'two' (not zero or one).

-if the column type is equal to 'two' accept only one another entry that contains 'one' (not zero or two).

Comment: would it not be better to use a trigger for that complex conditions?

Comment: What keeps you from providing a proper table definition (`CREATE TABLE` command)? And your Postgres version, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a better way than adding a generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE place
   ADD col int4range GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                        CASE WHEN type = 'zero' THEN INT4RANGE '[1,2]'
                             WHEN type = 'one'  THEN INT4RANGE '[1,1]'
                             WHEN type = 'two'  THEN INT4RANGE '[2,2]'
                        END
                     ) STORED
                     NOT NULL;
```

Then you can use that column in your exclusion constraint with the `&&` operator.